# Python text file strings into columns in Excel file

Tags: python, excel, string, windows

I'm really new to Python and currently doing this for my work. I would like to ask some newbie questions.

I have a text file with a number of rows following this format:

melted, swimming, liquified, liquidity, liquidness, liquid, liquid_state, smooth, fluent, limpid, fluid

All in form of strings.

I'd like to extract these strings into excel file in the following format - so that each 'set' of strings are in a separate column.

```
       |        A    |       B        |       C
------------------------------------------------------
  1    | melted      |   swimming     |  liquified 
------------------------------------------------------
  2    | liquidity   |   liquidness   |  liquid
```

My codes are as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
from nltk.corpus import wordnet
import xlwt
import xlrd

synonyms = []
for syn in wordnet.synsets('liquid'):
    for l in syn.lemmas():
        synonyms.append(l.name())
        A = set(synonyms)
        A = list(A)
        A = ', ' .join(str(e) for e in A)
#print(A)
with open('Output.txt', 'w') as file:
    print(A)
    file.write(A)
    file.close()

data = []
with open("Output.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        data.append([word for word in line.split(" ") if word])
print(data)

wb = xlwt.Workbook()
sheet = wb.add_sheet("New Sheet")
for row_index in range(len(data)):
    for col_index in range(len(data[row_index])):
        sheet.write(row_index, col_index, data[row_index][col_index])

wb.save("newSheet.xls")
```

But when I run my codes, the output is not as expected. It outputs as:

```
       |        A    |       B        |       C
------------------------------------------------------
  1    | melted, swimming, liquified, liquidity, liquidness, liquid 
------------------------------------------------------
  2    |             |                |
```

What is the problem with my codes..?

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**: I'd like to extract these strings into excel file in the following format
>
> ```
>        |     A       |       B        |     C 
> ---------------------------------------------------
>   1    | melted      |   swimming     |  liquified
> ```

**Three words** in one line, but according to your Questions Data, you have **6 words** in one text line.

> **Can't reproduce your Output**!
>
> ```
> 1    | melted, swimming, liquified, liquidity, liquidness, liquid
> ```

---

This is working for me:

```
one_line_of_data = "melted, swimming, liquified, liquidity, liquidness, liquid\n"

for line in f:
    liw = [word.strip() for x,word in enumerate(line.split(","))]
    data.append(liw[:3])
    data.append(liw[3:])

for row_index in range(len(data)):
    for col_index in range(len(data[row_index])):
        sheet.write(row_index, col_index, data[row_index][col_index])
```

***Tested with Python:3.4.2***